# How could I list all virtual machines under Virtual Box?

Tags: unix, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtualbox

How can I list all VirtualBox virtual machines, including those created by other users?

By default, the `VBoxManage list vms` command lists the VMs owned by the current user. But what if there are many VMs, created by different users? I would like to run a VM created by another user, but cannot find any, even though I know it exists somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox stores its data in your user profile directory - there's no "global virtualbox database" for the machine. You would have to get access to the virtualbox directory under the other user's profile.